# Pulseaudio & dac usb (smsl do300): is this normal behaviour to always show 48kHz?

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio

I listen to music with an Ubuntu 22.04 pc (Qobuz via Google Chrome or LibreFox) and a smsl do300 usb dac. I followed this guide to tweak pulseaudio: https://mclements.net/blogWP/index.php/2020/06/30/high-res-audio-on-ubuntu/.

Here is my pulseaudio conf:

> ; daemonize = no
> ; fail = yes
> ; allow-module-loading = yes
> ; allow-exit = yes
> ; use-pid-file = yes
> ; system-instance = no
> ; local-server-type = user
> ; enable-shm = yes
> ; enable-memfd = yes
> ; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
> ; lock-memory = no
> ; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11
nice-level = -15

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

resample-method = soxr-vhq
avoid-resampling = yes
; enable-remixing = yes
; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
; remixing-produce-lfe = no
; remixing-consume-lfe = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 60

; flat-volumes = no

; rescue-streams = yes

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 200000

default-sample-format = s24le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 96000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

; default-fragments = 4
; default-fragment-size-msec = 25

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0

> Blockquote

I am fine with that, but whatever the rate I play my dac shows 48kHz. Is this normal? Should my dac show the exact rate I am playing (I understand it should, but maybe I am wrong)? The dac shows the "default-sample-rate" I entered in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf as you can see in the file. Maybe I missed something, I am a very basic Ubuntu user.
Thank you!